# Online 3d modeling free software

Tags: windows, gratis, web-apps, 3d, modeling

Is there a free online 3d modeling site that is recommended for beginners?  I would prefer if it could export to *.obj so I could use it with pygame.

If not, then is there one that is less than 5 GB in size?
I am running out of storage on my tablet and I don't have money to buy a micro SD card for it.

I am using win10 x86 home edition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch up is a good one to use, there is a free web version as well as a premium version, but the free version is good enough for a beginner.

Here is the link: [sketchup.com](https://www.sketchup.com)

Answer (score 1):

I started off 3D modelling using this free online software called Tinkercad (https://www.tinkercad.com/). You're able to export to .obj .stl and .svg. It's really simplistic and great for beginners. It is also developed by Autodesk, one of the best-known companies for their CAD software.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't open source, but Onshape is real 3D solid modeling which runs in a browser. **There is no installation at all**. [It is free for students and educators](https://www.onshape.com/products/education?hsCtaTracking=28006f2c-d5c6-46ad-9e1e-32cd73f381d6%7C9ebb58b7-e237-493e-b77d-a789ad661024). [It imports and exports to many formats](https://www.onshape.com/cad-blog/import-export-onshape).

It works remarkably well and has a lot of power. There are extensive on-line learning resources at https://learn.onshape.com/.